# cordova - logo and parts of the web/mobile app not showing

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

I'm developing an application using cordova and so HTML CSS and JAVASCRIPT (+ some PHP).
The thing is, now my application only contains an IFRAME pointing to the domain and subdomain (containing all of my files, index.php, css flder js folder etc...)
I changed the logo of my application and a map.php file (containing a google maps etc).
I can see all hese changes applied when i access it through a web browser (even the ones from tablets and smartphones directly) but when i open the application (with the IFRAME), the logo is still the old one and the map.php page doesnt show or do the things it should !
Whereas i'm able to do some other changes and see them directly in the app !
I fyou have any ideas please enlight me i have really no clue about that...
Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like your content is being cached. You can probably make some changes on your server to adjust how the content is being read, but worst case, you can use some cache-busting on your URLs (that is, index.html?12345 -- and change the # at the end whenever you make a change).

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! is the ?12345 an example? This is what i should add at the end of my  link in my IFRAME right ? The thing is, i dont think it's a cache problem because the meta "no-cache" is present and i removed all the cache on the smartphone !

Comment: ?12345 is an example, yes. I've used it many times when the mobile browser tries to re-use a script or CSS file for whatever reason, and it always busts the cache. Perhaps your problem is different, but it would be worth a try.